# Using Java Google App Engine bulkloader to download entire datastore to one csv file

Tags: java, google-app-engine, bulkloader

I'm currently using the `--kind` parameter to specify which kind to download and the `--filename` to specify the name of the csv file to produce. The `--rps_limit`, `--bandwidth_limit` and `--batch_size` are used to speed up the download.

For example, to download my Game kind I'm using:

```
appcfg.py download_data --config_file=bulkloader.yaml --kind=Game --filename=game.csv --application=MyAppId --url=http://MyAppId.appspot.com/remote_api --rps_limit=500 --bandwidth_limit=2500000 --batch_size=100
```

So is there an appcfg.py command to download the entire datastore without being kind specific to one csv file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just omit the --kind flag entirely.  This works for me - but I don't use a config_file. I hope that doesn't complicate things.

Comment: It worked, thanks!
I used the following to download every kind to a single csv file:

`appcfg.py download_data --filename=backup.csv --application=MyAppId --url=http://MyAppId.appspot.com/remote_api --rps_limit=500 --bandwidth_limit=2500000 --batch_size=100`

I used the following to upload the single csv file back to the datastore:

`appcfg.py upload_data --filename=backup.csv --application=MyAppId --url=http://MyAppId.appspot.com/remote_api --rps_limit=500 --bandwidth_limit=2500000 --batch_size=100`

They are the same commands but just download_data and upload_data swapped around.