# Google App Engine: how to download datastore as XML or CSV

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to download my data from App Engine. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008929/using-java-google-app-engine-bulkloader-to-download-entire-datastore-to-one-csv-f/6010286#6010286), I'm using the following command to grab it as CSV:

```
appcfg.py download_data --filename=backup.csv --application=MyAppId --url=http://MyAppId.appspot.com/remote_api --rps_limit=500 --bandwidth_limit=2500000 --batch_size=100
```

But the resulting file is always a binary SQLite file, not CSV.

How can I get my data as CSV or XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the [section of the docs concerning the bulkloader](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html)? It describes in some detail how to do bulkloading and how to set up the configuration file that describes how to translate between CSV files and your datastore.

Comment: In particular, the `connector: csv` bit.

Comment: I have, and their lack of examples has left me bewildered. For example, right now I'm trying to export to XML, and it's complaining that I'm missing xpath_to_nodes. So I tried adding that in but I can't guess the syntax.

Comment: @Caffeine The command line you use in the question doesn't specify a config file, so I presumed you hadn't. Have you tried CSV exporting first? It's a lot more straightforward.

Comment: Ah, that was blessedly simple. I was hoping to get some kind of basic XML structure (kind of like how Java's XMLSerializer will derive a basic syntax from a bean), but apparently you need to spell it all out in the yaml. CSV isn't as structured as I'd like, but I can certainly read the data. Thanks very much.